# Swift: Apply "addTarget" to a UIButton in a different class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a class called `RecordViewFooter` where i create a `UIButton` called `microphoneButton`. I add as a `subview` and it looks beautiful.

However, when this button is selected i need to add something as a `subview` to my `ViewController`. So i did this in my `ViewController`:

```
    RecordViewFooter().microphoneButton.addTarget(self, action: "microphoneButtonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
    func microphoneButtonPressed(){
    print("microphone button pressed")
    volumeAdjuster = VolumeAdjusterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(volumeAdjuster!)
}
```

I can not figure out why it won't call the function when the button is selected. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the code for the IBAction tied to the button?

Comment: I don't have an IBAction but instead use "addTarget". They're the same correct?  @AdrianB

Comment: @NadalAlyafaie Have you allocated memory to RecordViewFooter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solved that problem by implementing following solutions :

1. First Prepare object of RecordViewFooter class. like here i create object of RecordViewFooter() class.

   ```
   var popViewObj = UINib(nibName: "RecordViewFooter", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! RecordViewFooter
   ```
2. now Write this code after subview done.

   ```
   popViewObj.microphoneButton.addTarget(self, action: "microphoneButtonPressed:",forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   ```
3. Now Add Selected button Event in your code:

   ```
   func microphoneButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
   {
       print("microphone button pressed")
       // Do Whatever u want...
   }
   ```
4. it will work fine.. i hope u will done with this code.

Comment: You have the function name for the button event wrong, but that wasn't the problem
This makes my viewController crash instantly when i go on it. Help please!

Comment: I wrote this: let volumeAdjusterViewObject = UINib(nibName: "RecordViewFooter", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! RecordViewFooter
        volumeAdjusterViewObject.microphoneButton.addTarget(self, action: "microphoneButtonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

Comment: Till now u facing problem.?

Comment: Now try with my updated code on here and don't forget ":" After selector event name.

Comment: Yea i didn't forget the ":" inside of the parameter. It crashes right when i go onto the viewController, not even when the button is selected. Its not the function, its the 1st and 2nd lines of code.

Comment: Can u mentioned code here which u write for placing subview inside in main view?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Comment: ok then check in your nib file how many views are on there? and whatever class u applied that given in viewbaseclass or not

Comment: it may that view which u load thats sequence is not on 0 position or class is not set properly

Comment: I believe the class is set properly because when I create the add Target within the class, it can be called correctly. Something is wrong with the code you gave me, but i believe your close!

Comment: This error can occure when you rename some files outside XCode. To solve it you can just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete and "Remove Reference") You re-import the files in your project and everything will be ok !

Comment: Also check that nib is installed in target or not.

Step 1: Click on your nib in Project Navigator (i.e. In First left tab)
Step 2: Go to File Inspector (i.e. In First right tab)
Step 3: Go to Target membership and tick on target in which you want to use your nib.

Comment: Check that nib file in Copy bundle resources or not
1.) Open Xcode Target 2.) Go to the "Build phases" tab 3.) Click the "Copy bundle resources" section 4.) Click the add button 5.) Add the missing Nib file if not on there then only.

Comment: hello @Nadal Alyafaie u got solutions or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified code:

```
RecordViewFooter().microphoneButton.addTarget(self, action: "microphoneButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func microphoneButtonPressed(button:UIButton){
    print("microphone button pressed")
    volumeAdjuster = VolumeAdjusterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(volumeAdjuster!)
}
```

Comment: Aw. Didn't work :/. The thing is, if i create the "addTarget" within the RecordViewFooter class, the button can be selected. It is only when i create the "addTarget" within the ViewController.

Comment: Let know in which function you have called RecordViewFooter().microphoneButton.addTarget.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I had to create an object from the class that i want to reference the global variable. Then do this:

```
    objectFromClass.globalVariable.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```